# Is there any way to flag suspected voter fraud?

Tags: support, flags, voting-fraud

Recently I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335570/preg-match-all-dont-return-result/42335716) and had my answer accepted. Another user subsequently offered a much better answer which I upvoted since it actually did what what OP asked for and was more helpful than mine. I was feeling all warm and fuzzy about all this - someone asking a question, getting helpful answers, and people being gracious and cordial toward each other.

Came back a few hours later and someone rolled through and just downvoted everything for no apparent reason. Is there any way to flag the voting activity itself so one of the mods might have a look about what happened here?

Comment: Moderators can't see individual downvotes, flagging it would be of no use. Downvoting all answers on a post isn't voting fraud, Voting fraud is when people co-ordinate votes on each other.

Comment: @BhargavRao - thanks.  I didn't realize mods can't see who voted for what.  I guess in that case it would be fruitless for them to look.

Comment: @yellowantphil - the only person who had been previously downvoted suddenly got upvoted at the same time.  makes it look like they were annoyed and downvoted everyone out of malice.  not saying that's what happened but my question wasn't about this specific instance anyway - i was just wondering about flagging votes in general.  since mods apparently aren't privy to individuals' voting actions, that pretty much answers my question.

Comment: The first comment says basically "don't use regex for this \[processing html/xml\]". Not saying that person downvoted everything, but someone with that concept in his/her head could have downvoted the question and all the answers which had a regex answer just based on that advice (which is really good advice honestly). This type of voting would certainly fall within acceptable behavior within the SO voting guidelines as helping people use the wrong method to do something can be seen as not useful.

Comment: I have suspected it too.  I have seen some very high rep folks consistently get 5 and 6 upvotes and sometimes double digit upvotes for simple answers that I could "almost" guarantee low rep folks wouldn't get.  It is almost as though they have a "following."  Of course, there is no proof but I still think it is happening.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you see voting fraud as such, use a custom moderator flag and explain the same, we'll look into it. Voting fraud is when you see unusual number of upvotes on a post in a very small amount of time. However, as you have mentioned:

> someone rolled through and just downvoted everything for no apparent reason. Is there any way to flag the voting activity itself so one of the mods might have a look about what happened here?

This is something which moderators can't inspect. Moderators can't see the individual downvotes. Hence flagging this would not be fruitful.

Again, if you observe the same over an extended period of time, that is, you are getting a downvote on all the answers you post (and as soon as you do so), then it might be a case of revenge downvoting. In this case you can flag for moderator attention.